# How to translate this query to use in a model of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a column called option with values of 0 and 1.
I want to format this data using yes/no.

This is my query

```
SELECT IF(option = 1, 'YES', 'No') AS Options FROM Table1
```

Can I do it using a where clause?

Something like :

```
MyModel.where(option: 1).format_to_yes
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying the data at the database layer, it's easy to create a custom getter on your model that will simplify access to string values for a field:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  def option
    case read_attribute(:option)
    when 1 then 'Yes'
    when 0 then 'No'
    end
  end
end
```

You could also use a ternary or traditional conditional, but I like using a switch because it's so readily apparent what's going on without *any* thinking.

Comment: In this case, you can use a hash instead of case statement: `{1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'}`.

Comment: StackLevel issues? `option` will continually call `option`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko That's a ternary, which I addressed.

Comment: @Ilya Not a bad option either. Surely there are many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: @engineersmnky Clearly the coffee has not hit this morning, haha. Fixed.

Comment: This is a good variant in case if you need other than `option` fields too. But, if the issue is to select __all__ `MyModel` instances and to get just 1 column, using `pluck` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
MyModel.pluck(:option).map { |o| o == 1 ? 'YES' : 'No' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `select`, like this:

```
MyModel.select("IF(option = 1, 'YES', 'No') AS Options")
```

If you want all model attributes (not just `option`), add `*`:

```
MyModel.select("*, IF(option = 1, 'YES', 'No') AS option")
```

Notice the use of `AS option` instead of `AS Options` to keep only one `option` attribute.